# How to monitor application events such as open, close, minimize in Ubuntu?

Tags: scripts, window, window-manager, monitoring, events

I would like to know if it is possible to monitor applications open/close/minimize events in Ubuntu. My initial goal is to monitor how many times I open telegram to check messages.

PS: I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS (X11).

Comment: It depends, are you on X (Not wayland)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Yes, X11, not wayland.

Comment: Very well possible. Needs a script and some explanation. I'll write a tiny example if noone is quicker than I am :), but not sure if it is today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Just for fun, since you are on X

Using python (or a bunch of other languages) We can use signals from [Wnck.Screen](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Screen.html) and [Wnck.Window](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Window.html) to keep an eye on the creation and/or state change of windows. This includes maximizing and minimizing windows.

That's exactly what the script below does. Subsequently, it maintains a logfile, that will be updated if you create, minimize or unminimize a window of a specific WM_CLASS (and so application). You can find the WMCLASS of the targeted application by opening a terminal, type `xprop WM_CLASS` + <kbd>Return</kbd>, then click on the windowsubject ("telegramdesktop" for telegram or something like that).

Mind that I made the script reset the logfile after each (logging) session, else the logfile would become huge over time.

#### What's in the logfile?

The logfile (`~/.windowlog.txt`) will keep record of creation, closure and state-change of window(s) of the given WM_Class. Each time the window is unminimized, the counter adds one, so at the end of the day, you can see the activity:

```
found window: Telegram
state changed: visual(1)
state changed: minimized
state changed: visual(2)
state changed: minimized
state changed: visual(3)
window closed:Telegram
new window:Telegram
state changed: visual(4)
state changed: minimized
state changed: visual(5)
```

*Note* that the script is written with a single window for the application in mind, like the one in your question. To keep a more detailed record *per window*, processing the data would require more sophisticated coding.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck
import os
import sys


class WatchWindow:

    def __init__(self, wmclass):
        self.visual = None
        self.count_visual = 0
        self.wnck_scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
        self.wmclass = wmclass
        self.logpath = os.environ["HOME"] + "/.windowlog.txt"
        self.run_watching()
        Gtk.main()

    def write_to_log(self, newline):
        with open(self.logpath, "a+") as logfile:
            logfile.write(newline + "\n")

    def readable_state(self, minimized):
        n = ""
        if not minimized:
            self.count_visual = self.count_visual + 1
            n = "(" + str(self.count_visual) + ")"
        return ["minimized", "visual"][[True, False].index(minimized)] + n
    
    def logstate(self, window, *args):
        old_state = self.visual
        new_state = window.is_minimized()
        # only register if minimized state really changed
        if old_state != new_state:
            self.visual = new_state
            message = "state changed: " + self.readable_state(self.visual) # log
            print(message)
            self.write_to_log(message)

    def log_new(self, screen, window):
        if  window.get_class_group_name().lower() == self.wmclass:
            message = "new window:" + window.get_name() # log new
            print(message)
            self.write_to_log(message)
            self.watch_window(window)
            self.logstate(window)

    def log_closed(self, screen, window):
        if  window.get_class_group_name().lower() == self.wmclass:
            name = window.get_name()
            self.visual = None
            print("window closed:", name) # log closed
    
    def watch_window(self, window, firstcall=False):
        if  window.get_class_group_name().lower() == self.wmclass:
            if firstcall:
                message = "found window:" + window.get_name()
                print(message) # log please
                self.write_to_log("found window: " + window.get_name())
                self.logstate(window)
            window.connect("state_changed", self.logstate)

    def run_watching(self):
        try:
            os.remove(self.logpath)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        self.wnck_scr.force_update()
        for w in self.wnck_scr.get_windows():
            self.watch_window(w, True)
        self.wnck_scr.connect("window-opened", self.log_new)
        self.wnck_scr.connect("window-closed", self.log_closed)

args = sys.argv[1:]
if not args:
    print("Insufficient arguments! We need a wm_class to watch...")
else:
    WatchWindow(args[0])
```

#### Set up

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `windowlogger.py` and *make it executable*
2. Test- run it in a terminal window, run it with the WM_CLASS as argument (I suppose `telegramdesktop`), so:

   ```
   /path/to/windowlogger telegramdesktop
   ```
3. See if the output in terminal is fine, see inside the logfile `~/.windowlog.txt` if all works as it should.
4. Add it to your startup applications if you like.

#### N.B

Possibly, you need to add one or more libraries, check the terminal output.

#### Logging window being active?

From a comment, I understand you consider the window as "used" (only) if it is the active window.
In that case we can make the script substantially simpler, since we *only* need to look at the `active_window_changed` signal. If we also log time usage (per usage / total use time), you can get clear insight how much time you spent, staring at the (any) telegram window. The logfile then looks like:

```
start_time:  woensdag, oktober 06 2021, 11:32:53
window activated (1)
window hidden or closed, was active: 0:00:04    total: 0:00:04
window activated (2)
window hidden or closed, was active: 0:00:06    total: 0:00:10
window activated (3)
window hidden or closed, was active: 0:00:12    total: 0:00:22
window activated (4)
window hidden or closed, was active: 0:00:07    total: 0:00:29
```

The script in that case:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime

class WatchWindow:

    def __init__(self, wmclass):
        self.visual = False
        self.count_visual = 1
        self.wnck_scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
        self.wmclass = wmclass
        self.logpath = os.environ["HOME"] + "/.windowlog.txt"
        self.total_time = 0
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.run_watching()
        Gtk.main()

    def write_to_log(self, newline):
        with open(self.logpath, "a+") as logfile:
            logfile.write(newline + "\n")

    def get_readable_time(self, elapsed):
        return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=elapsed))

    def log_active(self, *args):
        try:
            # active_class can be None, e.g. on startup
            active_class = self.wnck_scr.get_active_window().get_class_group_name()
        except AttributeError:
            active_class = ""
        newvisual = active_class.lower() == self.wmclass.lower()
        oldvisual = self.visual
        currtime = time.time()
        if newvisual != oldvisual:
            if newvisual:
                self.last_time = currtime
                message = "window activated (" + str(self.count_visual) + ")"
                self.count_visual = self.count_visual + 1
            else:
                winactive_time = currtime - self.last_time
                self.last_time = currtime
                self.total_time = self.total_time + winactive_time
                message = "window hidden or closed, was active: " + \
                          self.get_readable_time(round(winactive_time)) +\
                          "\t" + "total: " +\
                          self.get_readable_time(round(self.total_time))
            self.write_to_log(message)
        self.visual = newvisual

    def run_watching(self):
        try:
            os.remove(self.logpath)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        time_stamp_message = "start_time: " + time.strftime(" %A, %B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
        self.write_to_log(time_stamp_message)
        self.wnck_scr.force_update()
        self.wnck_scr.connect("active-window-changed", self.log_active)
        self.log_active()

args = sys.argv[1:]
if not args:
    print("Insufficient arguments! We need a wm_class to watch...")
else:
    WatchWindow(args[0])
```

Setup is the same.

Comment: Now we also need this on Wayland, so we can switch over ;)

Comment: @vanadium Hehe, right.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want. Additionally, I added an `active-window-changed` signal to monitor if the active window switches back to telegram.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sure, that will be great.

Comment: @SashaRAdler done.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Cool, thank you.